# How to store select queries as divs in EJS?

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql, server, ejs

I have created a PostgreSQL database where I store scores from a game. I have now successfully displayed them in the EJS file. The problem is, it is very ugly and nearly impossible to coordinate. I would need hundreds of lines to hardcode the possibilies (different lengths of usernames, scores, boolean value etc). This is how the output looks:

[image]

I have the following JS code for the server:

```
app.post('/users/leaderboard', async (req, res) => {
let username = {user: req.user.username}.user;
let leaderboard = req.body.lb;

//Used for hardcoding later
let headers= [];

// Local leaderboard
if (leaderboard == 'local') {
    pool.query(
        `select * from highscores
        where username = $1
        order by score desc`,
        [username],
        (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            // Header
            let header = "\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 Score" +
                         "\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 Date " +
                         "\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 Straight flush?";
            headers.push({row: header});

            // Add query elements to list, to later display in page
            let localScores = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
                let tmpDate = JSON.stringify(results.rows[i].date).slice(1, 11);
                let tmpScore = results.rows[i].score;
                let tmpSF = results.rows[i].straightflush;

                let fin = "\xa0 \xa0" + tmpScore +
                            "\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 " + tmpDate +
                            "\xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 \xa0 " + tmpSF;
                localScores.push({row: fin});
            }
            res.render('leaderboard', {headers, localScores});
        }
    )
}
```

I figured you could, somehow, put each username, score, date, and bool into a div, and center them. That could easily make this code much prettier.

This is the relevant HTML/EJS code:

```
<div class="center">
    <ul>
        <% if (typeof headers != 'undefined') { %>
            <% headers.forEach (func => { %>
                <li style="font-weight: bold;"> <%= func.row %> </li>
            <% }) %>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <ul>
        <% if (typeof localScores != 'undefined') { %>
            <% localScores.forEach (func => { %>
                <li> <%= func.row %> </li>
            <% }) %>
        <% } %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Edit: This is what happens when I change to tables:
EJS:

```
<div class="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <% if (typeof headers != 'undefined') { %>
                <% headers.forEach (func => { %>
                    <td style="font-weight: bold;"> <%= func.row %> </td>
                <% }) %>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="center">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <% if (typeof localScores != 'undefined') { %>
                <% localScores.forEach (func => { %>
                    <td> <%= func.row %> </td>
                <% }) %>
            <% } %>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is how it turns out:
[image]

Edit2: This is the generated HTML

[image]

Comment: Why you won't use the HTML table element? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: see Edit @kyziur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you create a second table instead of placing data inside the first one that has been created?

I guess you have this data structured in a proper way in JSON so it looks similar to that:

```
[{
   user,
   score,
   date,
   straight_flush
}]
```

So your code should look like this:

```
<div class="center">
<table>
    <tr>
        <% if (typeof headers != 'undefined') { %>
            <% headers.forEach (func => { %>
                <td style="font-weight: bold;"> <%= func.row %> </td>
            <% }) %>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
        <% headers.forEach (func => { %>
    <tr>
            <% if (typeof localScores != 'undefined') { %>
                <% localScores.forEach (func => { %>
                    <td> <%= func.row.user %></td> 
                    <td> <%= func.row.score %></td> 
                    <td> <%= func.row.date %></td> 
                    <td> <%= func.row.straight_flush%></td>
                <% }) %>
            <% } %>
     </tr>
        <% } %>
</table>
</div>
```

You need to create a new row each time you go to the next object in your array. In your example of a table, you create two rows. One is for the header and one is for data. I don't have a possibility to check my code but I think it should look similar. Please check and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It did not, I ended up with the same code you see at the bottom of my original post :/

Comment: Oh my mistake, sorry for that. I just copied it wrong. It should be <tr> create a header </tr> so headers are in first row. Then it should be - create a row for each object in the array. I fixed my answer. Could you please check it?

Comment: No difference I'm afraid. What seems to happen is that the whole thing gets passed as a single td..

Comment: Please check what HTML is generated.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by what HTML is generated?

Comment: EJS is a template engine. So you should have some HTML generated. So when you are reaching your page via URL (when you run your app) you see HTML (page), click F12 and check how looks HTML that is generated by your code and paste it here.

Comment: see second Edit. It seems the whole thing is counted as a single td, instead of being divided into several

Comment: Ok as we can see in the image you added. You are displaying all data from each row in one td. Why? Because of <td> <%= func.row %> </td>.  I think that you should be doing 4 td's because you got 4 properties and it should be 
 <td> <%= func.row.user %> </td>
 <td> <%= func.row.score %> </td>
 <td> <%= func.row.date %> </td>
 <td> <%= func.row.straight_flush%> </td>.

Check it and let me know so i will update answer.

Comment: Ok, so I will edit the answer so it can be helpful for other people.